# How to output Nexus3 logs in JSON format?

Tags: json, apache-karaf, nexus3

I'm have successfully deployed Nexus3 on openshift cluster via [Nexus3 Helm Chart](https://github.com/sonatype/helm3-charts/tree/master/charts/nexus-repository-manager).
In order to feed the nexus container logs in the EFK stack I want nexus container to output logs in JSON format.

I'm unable to find some documentation to change the logging format for Nexus3.

How can I modify the configurations in image so that the std output is in JSON and easily parsed?

Comment: Is it really related to apache-karaf ?

Comment: Yes, as nexus3 is using apache-karaf